# Postgres: Sum from multiple joins resulting in values being more than expected

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables: **invoices, invoice_payments, invoice_credit_notes**. I want to fetch all those invoices where the total paid amount is less than the `grand_total` amount in invoices table.

An invoice can have multiple invoice_payments as well as multiple invoice_credit_notes.

`invoice_payments` has `amount` and `discount` field in it.

`invoice_credit_notes` has `amount` field in it.

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT invoices.* FROM invoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_payments ON invoice_payments.invoice_id = invoices.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_credit_notes ON invoice_credit_notes.invoice_id = invoices.id 
GROUP BY invoices.id
HAVING ((COALESCE(SUM(invoice_payments.amount + invoice_payments.discount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(invoice_credit_notes.amount), 0)) < ROUND(invoices.grand_total, 0))
```

But there's an issue with my solution as there can be multiple invoice_payments or invoice_credit_notes the `(COALESCE(SUM(invoice_payments.amount + invoice_payments.discount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(invoice_credit_notes.amount), 0)` is returning an amount that is higher than the actual paid amout. This is most probably because multiple tables are being joined.

So, how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join against the results of the aggregation:

```
select inv.*
from invoices inv
  left join (
    select invoice_id, COALESCE(SUM(amount + discount), 0) as total_payments
    from invoice_payments
    group by invoice_id
  ) ip on ip.invoice_id = inv.id
  left join (
    select invoice_id, coalesce(sum(amount),0) as total_credit
    from invoice_credit_notes
    group by invoice_id
  ) icn on icn.invoice_id = inv.id
where coalesce(ip.total_payments,0) + coalesce(icn.total_credit,0) < ROUND(inv.grand_total, 0))
```

Comment: There's a slight issue though. Even after `COALESCE(SUM(amount + discount), 0)` the `ip.total_payments` is nil/null if there are no invoice payments associated. I had to use `where coalesce(ip.total_payments, 0) + coalesce(icn.total_credit, 0) < ROUND(inv.grand_total, 0)` is order to make this work. What might have caused this issue?

Comment: @AkshayGoyal: did you change the JOINs to LEFT JOINs? That would explain this behaviour

Comment: Yes, I did. Is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. That happens for those invoices where no invoice_payments or invoice_credit_notes exist. But I assumed you are only interested in those invoices where such things exist, that's why I used an inner join rather than an outer join.

Comment: I wanted to fetch all the unpaid invoices. If no invoice_payments or invoice_credit_notes are present then that invoice is considered to be unpaid. How to overcome this coalesce issue in case of left outer joins?